# Loading a reference property of a reference property inside an include EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have an entity that has a parent. That parent has a reference property. How would I load the reference 
property of the parent with the original entity as a starting point?

Something like

```
Context.Filings.Include(x => x.Parent.Include(y = >y.Petitioner)); //obviously second include doesn't even compile
```

Comment: If you do Go To Definition in VS on `Include` method, the Remarks section contains a lot of examples, including the one in question - *"To include a reference and then a reference one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Reference)*"

Comment: That was it, thanks! Submit it as an answer so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Context.Filings.Include(x => x.Parent.Petitioner);`

Courtesy of @IvanStoev